# Is Google Cloud Load Balancing a managed version of Envoy?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, reverse-proxy, envoyproxy

I'm comparing layer 7 HTTP(S) load balancers to use with Kubernetes on Google Cloud Platform.

GCP has their own managed service called [Google Cloud Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/).

Also popular to use with Kubernetes is [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/), an open-source "cloud native" proxy that has many contributions from Google staff.

Is Google Cloud Load Balancer a managed version of Envoy? Perhaps just with some added integrations with GCP's CDN? If they are not actually the same, what are they key differences between the two options (beyond just that one is managed and the other is self-deployed)?

Answer (score 0):

Right now the new version of Google Load Balancer uses Envoy proxy to handle advance traffic management ([here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https?hl=es-419#load-balancer-mode))